# How do I center these Twitter bootstrap 3 navbar links?

Tags: html, css, centering, navbar, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm wondering on how I can center the bootstrap 3's navbar menu items. I know they have included a `.nav-justified` class but that will just conflict with `navbar-nav` if used together. I belive it is being looked into by the dev team.

So is there any work around with CSS that I can achieve a  navbar that will keep the navbar menu items/links justified even when the container it is in is re-sized.

Here's a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wF5dW/) for you if you need it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `.nav-justifed` class is to be used with `nav-tabs` / `nav-pills` (see [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified)) and not `nav-bar`. The two concepts are very different and should not be confused.

However, you can achieve the effect you are looking for by adding the following `css`:

```
.navbar-nav.nav-justified > li{
    float:none;
}
```

`nav-justified`now plays nice with `navbar-nav`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified">
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wF5dW/3/).

Answer (score 5):

If using LESS, you can do the following:

```
.navbar-nav {
  .nav-justified;
}
```

Comment: perfect answer for people who are using less. +1